# Semântica correta para fazer uma div inteira se tornar uma âncora

Tags: html

Olá, possuo uma dúvida simples (acredito eu). Na imagem abaixo, eu gostaria que em qualquer lugar que eu clicasse redireciona-se para o link X preservando a web semântica, sem colocar a div inteira dentro de um `<a>`

segue o código que eu estou utilizando:

```
<div class="square square-dec square-color-red">
  <span class="nmrSquare">77</span>
  <i class="fa fa-file-text-o fa-5x iconSquare" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <span class="txtSquare">Cancelados</span>
</div>
```

[image: Toda está imagem deve ser uma âncora]

Comment: Você somente precisa adicionar um ID par a imagem, e no link que você clica, usar #seu_id no href

Comment: @Lai32290, mas não estou utilizando imagem, tudo foi feito através do css

Comment: Não é necessário que seja imagem, só precisa adicionar ID no elemento, a partir disso o elemento pode ser usado como âncora

Comment: A questão é que eu não quero que o elemento em si seja a âncora, por exemplo: quero que quando clicar em qualquer parte roxa (da imagem acima) seja redirecionado para o google.com (por exemplo). Facilmente isso aconteceria se eu adicionar todo o código que passei na pergunta dentro de um <a>, porém isso não vai de acordo com a web semântica

Comment: Entendi, você pode então englobar toda a div num elemento link, que é a forma mais recomendado para esse caso, ou então, você pode adicionar um evento de click para div, e fazer a ação de redirecionamento manualmente com JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partir do HTML5, o elemento `a` pode ter parágrafos, listas, tabelas e até mesmo seções, desde que não tenha conteúdo interativo (botões e outros links).

Com isso, não está incorreto adicionar a `div` dentro de um `a`.

Veja a  [documentação oficial da W3:](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element)

Tradução Google:

> O elemento `a` pode ser enrolado em parágrafos inteiros, listas, tabelas e assim por diante, mesmo seções inteiras, desde que não haja conteúdo interativo dentro (por exemplo, botões ou outros links). Este exemplo mostra como isso pode ser usado para fazer um bloco de publicidade inteira em um link:

```
<aside class="advertising">
 <h1>Advertising</h1>
 <a href="http://ad.example.com/?adid=1929&amp;pubid=1422">
  <section>
   <h1>Mellblomatic 9000!</h1>
   <p>Turn all your widgets into mellbloms!</p>
   <p>Only $9.99 plus shipping and handling.</p>
  </section>
 </a>
 <a href="http://ad.example.com/?adid=375&amp;pubid=1422">
  <section>
   <h1>The Mellblom Browser</h1>
   <p>Web browsing at the speed of light.</p>
   <p>No other browser goes faster!</p>
  </section>
 </a>
</aside>
```

---

No seu caso, basta adicionar o elemento `a` antes da `div`.

Caso não queira, pode fazer por javascript também, mas não vejo muita necessidade.

Veja abaixo um exemplo de ambas as formas.

```js
function ancora(web) {
  location.hash = "#" + web;
}
```

```css
div.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="square square-dec square-color-red" onclick="ancora('ancora');">
  <span class="nmrSquare">5</span>
  <i class="fa fa-file-text-o fa-5x iconSquare" aria-hidden="true">
</i>
  <span class="txtSquare">JavaScript</span>
</div>


<a href="#ancora">
  <div class="square square-dec square-color-red">
    <span class="nmrSquare">5</span>
    <i class="fa fa-file-text-o fa-5x iconSquare" aria-hidden="true">
</i>
    <span class="txtSquare">HREF</span>
  </div>
</a>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

<p id="ancora">Âncora</p>
```

Caso queira ler mais sobre isso, [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1827965/4843158) possui mais exemplos e explicações.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, não sabia que havia exceções para adicionar elementos dentro de um <a>!